# Как увеличить максимальный допустимый размер закачки файлов?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    if (ini_set("upload_max_filesize","30M")) {$a=1;} else {$a=0;}
    if (ini_set("post_max_size","40M")) {$b=1;} else {$b=0;}
    echo $a."<br>".$b;
?>
```

Где найти, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Перед куском кода ставь 4 пробела...

Comment: Кого найти?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы все правильно делаете. Но не факт что хостер разрешит менять эти параметры через ini_set.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя так. Насколько я знаю, эти параметры можно подправить только на сервере. Еще хостер может поддерживать заливку своего php.ini в корень сайта, там можно прописать свои параметры, но это надо у хостера спросить.